# Does Android support TLS compression?

Tags: android, ssl, compression

I'm trying to find a way for my app to use compression as per [RFC 3749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3749), but I don't find any options for enabling/specifying compression in Android's javax.net.ssl package.  I do see that [OpenSSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TLS_implementations), used by javax.net.ssl, supports DEFLATE compression.  Are there any open source libraries/implementations that allow this feature in Android?

Comment: Before considering turning on TLS compression, you might want to read about the [CRIME attack](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/20216/2435). It's probably more sensible to compress the data you send on top of TLS instead.